# Spark Driver vs MapReduce Driver on YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I know in spark you can run the driver program on the client machine if you specify `yarn-client` deployment mode. Or you can run it on a random machine in the cluster if you specify `yarn-cluster` mode.

Now my question is: In MapReduce applications where does the driver program runs? client or cluster?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `hadoop jar` in the terminal, that terminal session is the driver client

If you use Oozie, instead, for example, the driver will be deployed in the cluster

Comment: Okay so it behaves like Spark's client mode. I was just curious because in Spark client mode if you close the terminal from which you ran the spark-submit command the application will stop (and that's logical because you just stopped the driver). However, in MapReduce when you close the terminal the job keeps running, got any explanation for that behaviour?

Comment: The actual mapper/reduce tasks don't run in the terminal, only the status is reported there